I can't figure out a loop problem in my bubblesort, RISC-V
I'm doing school work, and the objective is to remove the noise of an 599x400 grayscale file. I already did the mean filter, but I can't figure how to make my median filter to work.
I suppose it's a problem on my median_for loop, since the program can end normally if I don't have it.
`
median_filter:
# valores iniciais
li t3, 239600        # Total de pixels, serve como contador
la a3, tempArray
median_for:
# array de 9 espaços
lbu t0, -600(a0)
sb t0, 0(a3)
lbu t0, -599(a0)
sb t0, 1(a3)

lbu t0, -598(a0)
sb t0, 2(a3)

lbu t0, -1(a0)
sb t0, 3(a3)

lbu t0, 0(a0)
sb t0, 4(a3)

lbu t0, 1(a0)
sb t0, 5(a3)

lbu t0, 598(a0)
sb t0, 6(a3)

lbu t0, 599(a0)
sb t0, 7(a3)

lbu t0, 600(a0)
sb t0, 8(a3)

# criar um pointer para o tempArray
li t0, 0

median_sort_outer:
li t2, 0
median_sort_inner:
lb t5, 0(a3)
lb t6, 1(a3)
bge t6, t5, no_swap
sb t6, 0(a3)
sb t5, 1(a3)
no_swap:
addi a3, a3, 1   # próximo byte do tempArray
addi t2, t2, 1
li t4, 8
blt t2, t4, median_sort_inner #se t2 < 8, volta para median_sort_inner
addi t0, t0, 1
li t5, 8
blt t0, t5, median_sort_outer  #se t0 < 8, volta para median_sort_outer
# adicionar mediana a a1
lb t2, 4(a3)
sb t2, 0(a1)

# Incrementações
addi a0, a0, 1          # avança um pixel no Buffer1
addi a1, a1, 1          # avança um pixel no Buffer2
addi t3, t3, -1         # decrementa o contador

bnez t3, median_for      # Se t3 != 0, repetir o loop

# fim da função
ret`

Also, here's my main:
`
main:
#utilizar o mean_filter
la a0, noisyImage      
la a1, Buffer1
jal read_image

la a0, Buffer1
la a1, Buffer2
jal mean_filter

la a0, noisyFinalMean
la a1, Buffer2
jal write_image
    
#utilizar o median_filter
la a0, noisyImage      
la a1, Buffer1
jal read_image

la a0, Buffer1
la a1, Buffer2      
jal median_filter    

la a0, noisyFinalMedian
la a1, Buffer2
jal write_image

# Encerrar o programa
li a0, 10              
ecall         

`
I was expecting it to work, since to me, the logic is correct.

Do you have a known working C version to compare with?  If so, you can single step both the assembly and the C code to see where it goes wrong.
